# Find unmatched value from a named range in columns

Tags: excel-formula, match, rows, multiple-columns

Please refer to the document: http://1drv.ms/1H3Ntk2

I am trying to figure out who is **not scheduled** for each week, in col F. The list of Staff members are in Col H. My data goes up to 52 weeks.

Comment: SO is not aimed to do your homework. Please show what you've done and we might help in case of issues.

Comment: I have tried using HLOOKUP:
=HLOOKUP(staff,B2:E2,1,FALSE)

R2 #N/A
R3 Katherine
R4 Kevin
R5 Robert
R6 Wayne
R7 #VALUE!

Comment: Sorry, Timed out.

I have tried using HLOOKUP:
=HLOOKUP(staff,B2:E2,1,FALSE)

Output in col F (from row 2-11)
#N/A; Katherine; Kevin; Robert; Wayne; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; #VALUE!

Where staff=named range

Comment: I am not trying to get my work done. Even suggesting functions/formulas would help. I don't mind trying to incorporate the logic to get the outcome. I am fairly new to Excel.

Comment: I figured out the answer, but I think, there could be a better way to do this. If there is one, I'd be interested to know. Thank you.

=IF(ISERROR((MATCH($H$2,B2:E2,0)))=TRUE, $H$2,IF(ISERROR((MATCH($H$3,B2:E2,0)))=TRUE, $H$3, IF(ISERROR((MATCH($H$4,B2:E2,0)))=TRUE, $H$4,IF(ISERROR((MATCH($H$5,B2:E2,0)))=TRUE, $H$5,IF(ISERROR((MATCH($H$6,B2:E2,0)))=TRUE, $H$6,"Data Error")))))

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have the following:

[image]

Put this formula in **F2** and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula; and then copy and fill down until the last row:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$6,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH($H$2:$H$6,B2:E2,0)),ROW($H$2:$H$6)-ROW($H$2)+1),1))
```

I hope it works. It is shorter than your own solution, at least.

Comment: Hi AHC. It is definitely short and reduces the chances of errors from using multiple 'IF' statements. Thanks very much for the solution.

Comment: @KaysKay 
please read [what should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and click the check mark below the vote count next to my answer.